# How could I to transform a pixel from a camera image plane to another camera image plane?

Tags: opencv

[image]

Two cameras , Calibration is done between them and both intrinsic and extrinsic matrices are obtained , I am able to get (U,V) of the first camera , How could i get (U,V) of the second camera ? What is the kind of transformation could be made ?
Positions of cameras is fixed

Comment: Please correct your question. In the question topic you ask about "transformation", but details of your question tells that you can't read (U,V) data from second camera, while being able to read data from the first camera.

Comment: Is it stereo homework? You seem to have 2 parallel cameras, am I right?

Comment: @zmechanic What i wanted is to find a way of transformation between 2 dimensional planes

Comment: @smttsp No this is not a homework , This is a project i am working on , I have two parallel cameras and i wanted to find the a way of transforming u,v values of plane to another.

Answer (score 0):

[Homography is the way a two 2D planes could be related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtzZT.png)

Comment: This just gives you the position, the position of a pixel when you rotate or/and translate an image. In this one, you have one image and modify it, however, in your case, they are different images taken from different location. So, this wont be very useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since these cameras are paralel to each other(i.e. `stereo`), y axis of a point(x,y) in the first image will remain the same in the second image, i.e . `y' = y`. Only x will change. ( y is vertical axis, x is horizontal).

There are some techniques to find x'. The easiest one is normalized cross correlation. Choose a window around the points, do normalized cross correlation. The result will be an array of width of the image.

Unless you are searching for a point in a smooth region, maximum value in your array (peak) is expected to be your matching point.

Alternatively, you can try SIFT/SURF feature but I am not expert on those. I only know there are functions you can use in Matlab (such as `detectSURFfeatures`).

Note that if you are using two different cameras, you have to calibrate both of them.